# How to print the smallest value of 10 numbers entered by the user in C++

Tags: c++

This program reads from the user 10 integers and prints the smallest number.
so here is an example of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int n,min=1;
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
    cin>>n;
    if (n<min)
        min = n;

}
cout <<min;

}
```

so here is my question: Why do I get "1" printed if I enter from 2 to 11 you will probably say because of the if condition nothing will be executed so it will print the "1" which is initialized so Is there another way to code this?

Comment: Will any of those numbers be less than one?

Comment: You can initialize `min` with the highest possible value it can hold. Try `int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();` + `#include <limits>`

Comment: Nothing will be less than one so the if case makes no sense here and it prints the "1".

Comment: You can also take the 1st iteration out of the loop - reading the 1st number into min before running your loop from i=1 to 10, without using int-value markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outputting `1` because that is the value you initialize `min` as, and the loop never updates `min` if all the values you enter are greater than 1.

You need to initialize `min` to the first value entered:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int n, min;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cin >> n;
        if ((n < min) || (i == 0))
            min = n;
    }
    std::cout << min;
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int n, min;
    cin >> min;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++) {
        std::cin >> n;
        if (n < min)
            min = n;
    }
    std::cout << min;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, put the values in an array and use [`std::min_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    int arr[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }
    std::cout << *std::min_element(arr,  arr+10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate a min from the values, you shouldn't initialize the variable. Assume the first value you have is the min, before starting the loop.

```
cin>>n;
min=n;
```

To be consistent with the fact that we want the min value of 10 numbers, we need to iterate one less time.

To do that, simply change

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<9 ; i++)
```

Comment: If he is reading like in your answer he have to change the loop limits.!!

Comment: Indeed. You have to iterate one less time if you do the first read outside.